# "npm install -g yo" on Windows 7

Tags: windows, installation, npm

on the following setup

Windows 7 Enterprise edition.

```
MyNodeJsCommandPrompt>node --version
v4.1.1
MyNodeJsCommandPrompt>npm --version
3.5.0
```

When I run the following

```
npm install -g yo
```

I get errors of this type

```
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename 'C:\MyCodeDirectory\npm\node_m
odules\yo\node_modules\update-notifier\node_modules\latest-version\node_modules\
package-json\node_modules\got\node_modules\read-all-stream\node_modules\pinkie-p
romise\node_modules\pinkie' -> 'C:\MyCodeDirectory\npm\node_modules\yo\node_modules\glob
by\node_modules\pinkie'
```

Can anyone help? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use :

```
npm cache clean
```

One time, it solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

This is what solved my problem.

I ran this once. Thanks to @Akram_Saouri

```
npm cache clean
```

However, that did not solve the problem by itself. After that I reran the command multiple times.

```
npm install -g yo
```

Every time I reran the command it kept throwing the same problem, but I noticed that it kept throwing the same problem for different files. And every time I ran it, it kept making some more progress but would stop on a different file, further down the installation process.

After multiple tries, it ran till the end with a bunch of WARNINGS but there was no ERROR at the end.

So, it was solved, with the steps mentioned below. But, truth be told, I am not sure exactly what solved the problem.

Thanks.